# How to safely and quickly archive and remove files in `pg_wal`

Tags: postgresql, docker

The server running my postgres database is quickly running out of storage, despite the database itself not being that large. After some digging, I found that an incorrect `archive_command` in my `postgres.conf` is making it such that files are never removed from `pg_wal`.  I'm relatively new to postgres, so I'm trying to learn how to best manage the records in the `pg_wal` directory. I am running postgres:14 in a Docker container. Here is what I'm trying to figure out:

1. I have updated my `postgres.conf` using the default `archive_command` in the postgres documentation: `archive_command = 'test ! -f /wal_dmp/%f && cp %p /wal_dmp/%f`. The backlogged `wal` files are now slowly being copied from the `/var/lib/postgres/data/pg_wal` directory into the `wal_dmp` directory. However, it seems that the files are only removed from `/var/lib/postgres/data/pg_wal` when I restart the Docker container. Is there a configuration setting I can use to make this happen operationally? Additionally, this is happening very slowly. Is there any way to speed this process up?
2. Every night, we create a database backup with `pg_dump`. Based on this backup schedule, I don't think I would ever need to perform a point in time recovery more than 24 hours in the past. From my understanding, this means I should only need to keep wal archives for ~24 hours and could delete the archives in `wal_dmp` after that time has elapsed. Is there a best practice for removing old wal archives that are no longer needed?

In summary, my server's storage is quickly filling up and I need to learn how to efficiently and safely remove files in `/var/lib/postgres/data/pg_wal` that are taking up this storage.

Comment: PITR must start with a base backup (not pg_dump) so you need to keep WAL all the way back to one of them. Or if you don't have any of them, there is no point in keeping an archive at all.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you can afford a downtime, since you mention that you are able to "restart the Docker container" -- I assume you've done this more than a couple times, which led you to discover that WAL files get removed when the Docker container restarts.  If this the case, I can think of a handful of approaches:

1. If this is not a production machine, I would suggest that you start a new cluster from one of your nightly dumps, and ensure that your configuration is correct.  That way, you don't need to wait for the WAL files to get processed and removed.
2. If you are able to afford stopping the container, then my next question is -- can you add a new volume and move your WAL files to that new volume?  Or if you are using LVM, can you expand the volume?
3. If you repeatedly issue `CHECKPOINT` in your `psql` prompt, you may see the WAL files being removed more quickly

To answer your second question in the original post, you cannot use PITR until you have created a basebackup (a basebackup is basically a snapshot of your entire `PGDATA` directory).  If you have created a basebackup using `pg_basebackup`, you are able to restore anywhere from when the basebackup was taken, up to the end of your WAL file sequence.  As mentioned by jjanes in the comments, having a `pg_dump` backup is not a basebackup.

Comment: Thank you for your response! So there is essentially no point in archiving the wal files if I'm not occasionally making a `pg_basebackup`? If that is the case, then I guess I'm trying to figure out a `postgres.conf` configuration that will minimize the total storage consumed by wal files. Can this just be tuned with the `wal_recycle`, `max_wal_size` and `wal_keep_size` settings?

Also, to clarify, I've been doing all this experimenting on a test machine, and plan to apply the changes to the production machine when I get evertyhing figured out!

Comment: if you don't plan to do PITR or replication, you can optionally turn `archive_mode = off` (or `archive_command = '<empty string>'`), and then just rely on `max_wal_size` to limit how big your `pg_wal` directory becomes.  Otherwise, just make sure your `archive_command` is set properly, and you should be totally fine